# Sum n values of n-lists with the same index in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, plot, random

For example, I have 5 lists with 10 elements each one generated with random values simulating a coin toss.

I get my 5 lists with 10 elements in the following way:

```
result = [0,1] #0 is tail #1 is head
probability = [1/2,1/2]
N = 10
list = []

def list_generator(number): #this number would be 5 in this case
    for i in range(number):
        n_round = np.array(rnd.choices(result, probability, k=N)) 
        print(n_round)

list_generator(5)



And for example I would get this
[1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1]
[1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1]
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
```

**How can I sum only the numbers of the same column, I mean, I would like to get a list that appends the value of 1+0+1+0+0 (the first column), then, that list appends the sum of each second coin toss of each round i.e. 1+1+1+0+0 (the second column), and so on with the ten coin tosses**
(I need it in a list because I will use this to plot a graph)

I have thought about making a matrix with each array and summing only the nth column and append that value in the list but I do not know how to do that, I do not have much knowledge about using arrays.

Comment: What code have you tried? And is this a homework problem?

Comment: I have been trying with nested for loops and np.matrix() but nothing were not working. No, this is not homework, it only is a very special case that helps me to understand how python works with matrices and arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your function `return` a 2d numpy array and then `sum` along the required axis. Separately, you don't need to pass probability to `random.choices` as equal probabilities are the default.

```
import random
import numpy as np

def list_generator(number):
    return np.array([np.array(random.choices([0,1], k=10)) for i in range(number)])

a = list_generator(5)

>>> a
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])

>>> a.sum(axis=0)
array([3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

Comment: What's working isn't "using using np.array with another np.array," but rather actually *returning* something from the `list_generator` function. In your original code, you didn't return anything from your function. Instead, you just *printed* the rows of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) to generate your randomized data. Then use `sum` to get the sum of the columns:

```
import numpy as np

N = 10

data = np.random.randint(2, size=(N, N))

print(data)
print(data.sum(axis=0))
```

---

```
[[1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1]]
[7 2 4 8 4 7 3 6 8 8]
```